# Dismiss snackbar when network is connected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-snackbar

Don't understand why `snackbar` in `else` doesn't work correctly and doesn't dismiss my `snackbar`?

```
private fun showNetworkMessage(isConnected: Boolean) {
    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(
        findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
        this.getText(R.string.warning_no_internet_connection), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
    )
    val snackBarLayout = snackbar.view as Snackbar.SnackbarLayout
    for (i in 0 until snackBarLayout.childCount) {
        val parent = snackBarLayout.getChildAt(i)
        if (parent is LinearLayout) {
            parent.rotation = 180f
            break
        }
    }
    snackbar.view.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
        snackbar.dismiss()
        true
    }
    if (!isConnected) {
        snackbar.show()
    } else {
        snackbar.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to keep `snackbar` global when showing it. When dismissing it try to use the `snackbar.dismiss()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the `snackbar` global:

```
var snackbar: Snackbar? = null

private fun showNetworkMessage() {
   snackbar = Snackbar.make(
        findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
        this.getText(R.string.warning_no_internet_connection), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
    )
    val snackBarLayout = snackbar.view as Snackbar.SnackbarLayout
    for (i in 0 until snackBarLayout.childCount) {
        val parent = snackBarLayout.getChildAt(i)
        if (parent is LinearLayout) {
            parent.rotation = 180f
            break
        }
    }
    snackbar.view.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
        snackbar.dismiss()
        true
    }
    snackbar.show()
}

private fun dismissNetworkMessage() {
    snackbar?.dismiss()
}

private fun showNetworkMessage(isConnected: Boolean) {
    if (!isConnected) {
        showNetworkMessage()
    } else {
        dismissNetworkMessage()
    }
}
```

Comment: In `dismissNetworkMessage` u mean `snackbar.dismiss()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the declaration of the `Snackbar` out of the function and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Declare Global variable,

```
 var snackbar: Snackbar? = null
```

Changes in function,

```
  private fun showNetworkMessage(isConnected: Boolean) {
        if (snackbar == null) {
            snackbar= Snackbar.make(
                    findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
                    this.getText(R.string.warning_no_internet_connection), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
            )    
        }
```

Comment: mb `var`? not `val`?